# How to redirect the standard output to a in-memory structure in Java?

Tags: java, output

Is there any way to redirect the stdout to a in-memory data structure so I can read it later without hard-drive operations?

Actually, I want to ClassLoader to run two programs, then capture and compare their outputs. I have to run lots of test cases so I don't want to redirect there output to temp files, since hard disk is really slow.

Comment: You can use in memory logger to log into memory

Comment: *fge* has a good answer to the specific question, but the specific question is almost certainly a bad idea. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: +1 using the standard output to store some data doesn't sound like a good idea (of course I don't know the context though...)

Comment: I've described the scenario. Thx for your comments by the way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this at the start of your program:

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(out);
System.setOut(stream);
```

However, beware of uncontrolled growth of such a stream, you may saturate your memory if you're not careful. And note that this will take care of stdout but *not* stderr (for this you need to `.setErr()` too.

See also the [javadoc for `ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).

---

final note: why do you want to do that anyway?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I want to do is added to the question.

Comment: Uhm, "classloader" and "execute"? Sorry, I don't get it; do you want to run `main()`s?

Comment: Yup, the two programs both have their own `main()`s.

Comment: Uh, I'm confused now. Do you want to run these in separate JVMs?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English... No, I run them in one JVM. There's a coordinator class to runn the two programs and gather their outputs. Coordinator will call ClassLoader to execute the `main()` of the two programs.

Comment: And why are they `main()`s? Can't they be classes in their own right?

Comment: The two programs are just subjects and I only have their `.class` files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the output of two *programs*, I suggest using [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). The `Process` object returned by `ProcessBuilder.start()` will give you access to the standard streams of the child processes, and you can read them at your leisure.

This will also give you the benefit of running the child processes concurrently. And it won't risk running out of permgen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Java Caching System](http://jakarta.apache.org/jcs/index.html) to store data. Refer this for more [information](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13924_01/coh.340/e14135/loaddata.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion:

Write your own wrapper method to encapsutlate the stdout and pushing of the output text to an in-memory datastructure. Something like this:

```
public static mySysout(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
    // add the input msg to your datastructure
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion not not for me, because I'm running two programs that written by others, and I want to capture their outputs. Since I cannot access the source code, I can only read their outputs from stdout, which I can redirect.